# Django: render form field label without explicitly calling it

Tags: python, django

I have a form like this:

```
class RoomForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
    departure_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
```

I am rendering its country field to the template like this:

```
{{ form.country }}
```

However the field gets diplayed without a label, even if I specify it in the form class like this:

```
country = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Country')
```

So in order to render the label to the template I have to do like this:

```
{{ form.country.label }}{{ form.country }}
```

Is there a way to only write `{{ form.country }}` and still have the label rendered to template?

Comment: Is there any cause you are not using the `as_*` methods (like `as_p()`) of the form?

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: isn't it: `{{ form.country.label_tag }}{{ form.country }}`?